# How to resize a node independently along a direction/axis (+x, -y, +y, etc.)?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

I have a node with a resize handle for each direction (+x, -x, +y, -y, +z, -z). When the user grabs the handle to resize, it should grow in that direction only. The user can also resize multiple times in different directions.

By default, when increasing node.scale.x it will grow from both directions on the x-axis.

From my research, it seems I need to adjust the pivot property - however, I'm trying to figure out how to have multiple pivots for each direction.

Comment: You can change its [pivot](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/1408044-pivot) before/after your translation

Comment: Wouldn't changing the pivot then affect the previous transform? @Alexander

Comment: Not sure, give it a shot and find out!

Comment: Confirming this does not work. When a pivot is changed, all the existing transforms (in my case, resize/scale) are updated to conform to the new pivot. @Alexander

Comment: What if you combined your scaling with a translation, which moves the pivot by half increase (or decrease) in size? E.g if your sprite is 100 px across and you drag it’s right edge out by 20 px, then you should move it’s pivot left by 10 px

Comment: @Alexander that's a great idea! will give it a try and report back.